# How do I use a filter to add a domain object to the request scope in Play Framework 2.x

Tags: scala, filter, playframework-2.1

I've written a filter to do authentication, however the next step is to have the user profile object available to handlers further down the chain.

I've seen how secure social handles this by wrapping the controller api.  I was wondering if there was a way to do it in the filter API by somehow wrapping the request header

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `play.api.mvc.WrappedRequest` with your own version. The problem then is that you need to do pattern matching in your controller methods.

The suggested solution is to use action composition that will supply a typed parameter. More information can be found here: [Scala Action composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaActionsComposition).